# how to run apache and nginx on the same port 443

Tags: apache, docker, nginx, proxy, port

I have 3 projects (project 1, project 2, project 3) running with apache2 and via port 443. Now I move project 1 running independently through docker environment (nginx, mariadb). I'm having an error that i can not start nginx in docker environment. I spent a lot of time to find out but there is no solution. Who can help me? Thank you very much and I am very sorry for my poor English level.

Comment: You cannot have two services bind to the same port, that simply is not possible. What you _can_ do is that you use one as a frontend to the other. So for a special set of requests to the frontend serviceyou relay those requests to the backend service and forward the response given by that to the client. That is a standard approach to a number of scenarios. Take a look at apache's proxy module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: First, you need to provide more info about the issue( what is the architecture now and needed).
Second, You can't have two apps running on the same port(sending on the same port exactly and that's the case), maybe you need to configure you apache to use 443(seems to be the ssl port) and forward traffic to the nginx when needed for the project running behind nginx.

Comment: We need the error code or message.